# How to compress csv gzip's smaller than a 100mb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, compression

I have a df that I have written as a gzip using the following lines of code:

```
df.to_csv('filepath/file.csv.gz',compression='gzip',sep=',',index=False)
```

The above line outputs a 117mb gzipped file. How can I get the file size even smaller with gzip functionality in `to_csv`?

Edit:

used this line of code to determine how much memory I am using:

```
df.info(memory_usage='deep')
```

Got

```
memory usage: 9.9 GB
```

Comment: reduce the memory of your df?

Comment: @d_kennetz how would I do that? very new at this? take out data I can not do.

Comment: The most immediate thing I can think of is to assign datatypes to your df columns. I will show a potential example of what I am talking about. It would be good if you could post an example of your dataframe.

Comment: @d_kennetz thank you

Comment: @d_kennetz made a edit regarding memory size

Comment: Also might be helpful to know what the uncompressed size of the file is; i.e. if you export it uncompressed, how large is the file?

Comment: its 9.9gb or 10gb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about as minimal as I could make my response. It is important to understand memory consumption by dataframes and what dtypes consume more memory. I would seriously recommend [this page](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/) for learning more about memory.

Suppose I have a small dataframe that looks like this called numbers:

```
   Number Number2 Number3
0       1     "1"     One
1       2     "2"     Two
2       3     "3"   Three
3       4     "4"    Four
```

and I wanted to check the dtype of numbers:

```
print(df.dtypes)
>>> df.dtypes
Number      int64
Number2    object
Number3    object
dtype: object
```

We can see that column 2 is being treated as an object, even though everything in this column is just an integer surrounded by quotes. In some circumstances, you may want to treat your int as a string (for example if you are trying to do some type of string matching), then you do not want to convert the type from object to int. But say in this case, that does not matter and you are okay with converting. Let's check our memory usage using this nice little pandas object memory checker:

```
def mem_usage(pandas_obj):
    if isinstance(pandas_obj,pd.DataFrame):
        usage_b = pandas_obj.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
    else: # we assume if not a df it's a serie
        usage_b = pandas_obj.memory(deep=True)
    return "{:03.2f} B".format(usage_b)
print(mem_usage(df))
### >>> mem_usage(df)
### '459.00 B'
```

Let's say I can afford to change dtype from object to int (we need to drop the quotes first):

```
df['Number2'] = df.Number2.str.replace('"', '')
df['Number2'] = df.Number2.astype(int)
print(df.dtypes)
### >>> df.dtypes
### Number      int64
### Number2     int32
### Number3    object
### dtype: object

print(mem_usage(df))
### >>> mem_usage(df)
### '299.00 B'
df.to_csv('./Desktop/numbers_fixed.csv', index=False)
```

So just like that, by changing a dtype we went from 459B of memory to 299B. Think of if that was a large dataset that would be 1.5X memory reduction just by changing a dtype. I am not saying to do this arbitrarily, but if you are processing external data or you are simply parsing your df incorrectly this type of thing can happen. Ints or floats can be read in as objects and you will see a huge memory reduction just by changing the datatype. Just to show this carries over to file creation see the image:

[image: Memory Reduction]

Comment: this is an amazing explanation. I just did what you suggested with the dtypes, and my memory definetly went down. I would upvote this many times if I could. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help! I found this out on a 10gig dataset myself which was reading in an int as an object. Saved me some serious memory consumption!